# return type Vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector, multiplication

I'm currrently trying to write a program with a vector return type. It keeps crashing. I think the problem is the the compiler isn't initializing the memory for a new vector, during the vector creation. But i'm not too sure what the issue is. If someone could help, It's much appreciated. TY.

```
//Settings-->compiler-->(Have g++ follow the c++11 ISO c++ language standard [-std=c++11]

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void displayVector(vector<double> &);
vector<double> calcVolts(vector<double> &U, vector<double> &V);


int main()
{
vector<double> current {10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98};
vector<double> resistance { 4.0, 8.5, 6.0, 7.35, 9.0, 15.3, 3.0, 5.4, 2.9, 4.8};
//displayVector(current);
//displayVector(resistance);
calcVolts (current, resistance);

}

void displayVector(vector<double> &object)
{
  for (int R = 0; R <object.size(); ++R)
    {
        cout<< setw(5)<< R+1<< "\t"<< object[R]<<endl;
    }
}

vector<double> calcVolts(vector<double> &U, vector<double> &V)
{
    std::vector <double> Voltage;
    if ((U.size() == V.size()) == false )
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Matrix Multiplication: Size do not match.\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int R = 0; R <U.size(); ++R)
        { 
        Voltage[R] = U[R]*V[R];
        }
        return Voltage;
     }
}
```

See comment from @Nandu and @soulsabr

Answer:

From @Soulsabr:
vector prior to intitialization should also declare its size.

From @Nandu: 
Local variables do not have return type.

From @Soulsabr: 
{You most certainly CAN return it. In the case of a std::vector a copy will be made so that the local one can be destroyed as it goes out of scope. what you absolutely CANNOT do is return a pointer to a local object.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int R = 0; R <U.size(); ++R)
{ 
    Voltage[R] = U[R]*V[R];
}
```

Here is your first issue.  Voltage is an empty vector and you are trying to put something where nothing exists.  Try creating your vector like

```
vector<double> voltage(U.size());
```

That should help.  Also, I'm surprised you don't get an error for the possibility that you may not return anything at all.

Comment: thank you very much. vector prior to intitialization should also declare its size.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer would be a nice thing.

Comment: theres 2 helpful advice that create the correct answer @soulsabr

Comment: If you are talking about Nandu I would be careful.  His/her first statement is absolutely wrong.  His second statement is a good practice to get into the habit of.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot return local variable as the return type

```
vector<double> calcVolts(vector<double> &U, vector<double> &V)
{
    std::vector <double> **Voltage**;
    if ((U.size() == V.size()) == false )
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Matrix Multiplication: Size do not match.\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int R = 0; R <U.size(); ++R)
        { 
        Voltage[R] = U[R]*V[R];
        }
        return **Voltage**;
     }
}
```

pass in vector to return the result.

```
vector<double> UV;
calcVolts (current, resistance,UV);

 calcVolts(vector<double> &U, vector<double> &V, vector<double>& UV)
{
    if ((U.size() == V.size()) == false )
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Matrix Multiplication: Size do not match.\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int R = 0; R <U.size(); ++R)
        { 
        UV[R] = U[R]*V[R];
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Local variables do not have return type.

Comment: You most certainly CAN return it.  In the case of a std::vector a copy will be made so that the local one can be destroyed as it goes out of scope.  what you absolutely CANNOT do is return a pointer to a local object.